Evaluate the accuracy if a calculation against a benchmark dataset
I calculated the value of a set of objects based on several attributes and  rules. I have a benchmark dasates of objects and expected values.
How can i tell how good my calculation are in matching the benchmark?
Which statistical tool do you think i can use and how?
